# What type is an unchained eidolon

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example, does an unchained elemental eidolon get the [elemental subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-elemental)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### They gain the subtype, but not its features

From the rules on [Unchained Eidolons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained):

> The first time a summoner calls his eidolon, he **must decide on its subtype**. The eidolon's subtype determines a number of its base statistics and abilities, as well as its overall look and theme. The subtype also determines what sort of evolutions the summoner can select for his eidolon using the evolution pool. Once the choice of subtype is made, it cannot be changed.
>
> [...]
>
> **Name**: This is the name of the eidolon's subtype. **The eidolon gains this as a subtype, but unless otherwise noted, it does not gain any of the features, abilities, or weaknesses of that subtype**.

(emphasis mine) Do note that most of the base evolutions grant the Eidolon the traits of their subtype. For example, an Elemental Eidolon gains immunity to flanking at 12th level, and immunity to critical hits and precision damage at 16th.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I missed part in the Name description, so it made very little sense to me that they kept saying subtype while giving abilities that were included in that subtype. Thanks for tracking that down :)